# How to calculate the sum of values in an Excel column using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to calculate the sum of values from excel column cells:

```py
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.open("AAB.xlsx")
wb=book
sheet = book.active
ws=sheet

column_name = 'Услуги по доставке товара покупателю'
for column_cell in ws.iter_cols(1, ws.max_column):  # iterate column cell
    if column_cell[0].value == column_name:    # check for your column
        j = 0
        for data in column_cell[1:]:    # iterate your column
            a=data.value
            b=float(a)
            
            
            print (sum(b))
        break
```

The following error appears:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Excel/df.py", line 16, in <module>
    c = math.fsum(b)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: b=float(a); sum(b) what do you expect from this to happen? you probably want to do something with your j=0. Use it to store the final sum there. You probably also can do `sum(column_cell[1:])` but I'm not with that module

Answer (score 0):

The sum function can be use only on an iterable like lists or tuples...
while b is a float,
indeed if you want to cumulate you must have a list of cummulable integers or floats